# Serialization fails only if a member of an object was data bound?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, serialization, data-binding

I'm quite new to C# and WPF, so I might be overlooking something.

I have a rather simple structure of classes as seen below:

```
[Serializable]
class ModuleList
{
    public ObservableCollection<Module> Items
    {
       get;
       set;
    }

    public ModuleList()
    { 
       Items = new ObservableCollection<Module>();
    }
}

[Serializable]
class Module : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private string name;
   public string Name
   {
      get
      {
         return this.name;
      }
      set
      {
         if(this.name != value)
         {
            this.name = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
         }
      }
   }
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
   {
      if(this.PropertyChanged != null)
      {
         this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
      }
   }
}

[Serializable]
class SpecializedModule : Module
{
   public SpecializedModule()
   {
      mode = false;
   }

   private bool mode;
   public bool Mode
   {
      get
      {
         return this.mode;
      }
      set
      {
         if(this.mode != value)
         {
            this.mode = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Mode");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

It's basically a list with some utility methods (omitted here) in the ModuleList class. This list is used as a member of another class, which only contains string/int/bool members otherwise. Serializing this object (on Window close) works without any problems, as does de-serializing.

There is also a second ModuleList object, containing all of the modules I have. Each ModuleList is bound to a ListView in the UI, with the user being able to move the items between the two module list to "select" modules.

As my next step, I turned to data binding. I have an external xaml file, that is loaded using `XamlReader.Load`:

```
<Grid Name="grdDummy" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
<CheckBox Content="on" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,66,0,0" Name="chkMode" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="{Binding Mode}"/>
```

The loading happens once the user clicks on any "selected" module, with the data context of the Grid being set to the corresponding Item of the list:

```
loadGrid("Module.xaml"); // XamlReader.Load in there
int idx = modListSel.getItemIndex("name_of_module");
if (idx != -1)
{
   grdModCfg.DataContext = (modListSel.Items[idx]); // this is a "SpecializedModule" object
}
```

Now comes the problem. As soon as any module that has such a data binding is loaded in the UI, serializing fails. Removing the data binding from the xaml file makes the object serializable again. Back when the xaml was part of the UI instead of being loaded dynamically, serialization worked even with databinding.

Any idea, why that is happening, and how should I go about fixing it?

edit:

By "fails" I mean that the program just aborts execution at the `BinaryFormatter.Serialize()` function. Surrounding it by a try/catch block, I can now see a `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException` is thrown.

The extended message is: "The type "System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventManager" in Assembly "WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" is not marked as serializable."

I added the definition of `NotifyPropertyChanged` in my Module class listing above, looks like I forgot to do it when I was cutting the unimportant parts, sorry.

Comment: define "fails"; what happens?

Comment: Show the declaration of `PropertyChanged` event in your `Module` class. I suspect you didn't decorate it with `[field: NonSerialized]` attribute.

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly the same situation, but I had a similar issue when serializing bound data with JSON. Both WPF and the serialization required the data to have affinity with the thread that works on the data (I guess to maintain thread safety). I fixed it by making anything connected to dependency objects Freezable, then explicitly let the serialization/deserialization be done in a separate thread context.

Comment: @IvanStoev: you're right, adding that fixes the problem. I'm not sure I understand why it worked before I started loading xaml dynamically, or rather, shouldn't it have thrown the exception when serializing the object without the databinding in the first place?

Comment: It depends if data binding infrastructure has subscribed to the `PropertyChanged` event or not at the time you try to serialize. The problem appears when there is a subscriber, in which case the binary serializer (w/o that attribute) will try to serialize the **object** that is subscribed and all objects it references etc.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation (and the solution), I guess I haven't thought of it that way. Now... how do I mark this as answered :D